# error：argument type 'xx' is incomplete for hiding call to ptrace example code

Tags: linux, android-ndk, cross-compiling, ptrace

I'm testing an antidebug solution with ptrace method; and i compile the program by using ndk21e cross-compile.
The problem is that it compiles successfully with gcc, but fails with ndk cross-compile.

> ndk cross-compile compiles all other programs without problems

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/ptrace.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
void *handle;
long (*go)(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid);

// get a handle to the library that contains 'ptrace'
handle = dlopen ("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);

// reference to the dynamically-resolved function 'ptrace'
go = dlsym(handle, "ptrace");

if (go(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0) < 0) {
    puts("being traced");
exit(1);
}

puts("not being traced");

// cleanup
dlclose(handle);

return 0;
}
```

And  it shows the error like the picture as follow：
[gcc compileresult and cross-compile error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Z80.png)

How can i solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can replace the enum type with `int`, but it is still possible that the platform doesn't support ptrace.

Comment: How about calling `ptrace` directly, without dlopen/dlsym?